# Rails 3.2.8 Actionmailer - stack level too deep PLUS uninitialized constant Mail::Ruby19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm following a tutorial referenced in a StackOverflow post for a simple contact form. Tutorial is here: http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

Everything is copy/paste and change a few values for my domain and mail settings. Running into two very strange errors: When I first submit the contact form, I get a :

> stack level too deep
>
> Rails.root: /Users/me/application
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> This error occurred while loading the following files:
>
> mail
>
> mail/parsers/rfc2822_obsolete

If I resubmit without restarting the rails app, I get:

> uninitialized constant Mail::Ruby19
>
> Rails.root: /Users/me/application
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>
> app/mailers/notifications_mailer.rb:1:in `'
>
> app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:11:in `create'
>
> This error occurred while loading the following files:
>
> mail

The sections I feel might be relavent are:

```
class NotificationsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "feedback@mydomain.com"
  default :to => "me@gmail.com"

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message
    mail(:subject => "mydomain Feedback")
  end
end

class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :body

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end

class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])        
    if @message.valid?
        NotificationsMailer.deliver_new_message params[:message]
      # NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

The rest of the templates are very straightforward and rendering fine.

Also, attaching the gemfile in case I missed some obvious conflict in there:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'redis', '2.1.1'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jade'
gem "haml", ">= 3.1.7"
gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.3.5", :group => :development
gem "hpricot", ">= 0.8.6", :group => :development
gem "ruby_parser", ">= 2.3.1", :group => :development
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.11.4", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "email_spec", ">= 1.2.1", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.3.0", :group => :test, :require => false
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.9.1", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.1.2", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 4.1.0", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.1.0.1"
gem "devise", ">= 2.1.2"
gem "cancan", ">= 1.6.8"
gem "rolify", ">= 3.2.0"
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.0.4"
gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.1", :group => :development
gem "hub", ">= 1.10.2", :require => nil, :group => [:development]
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem "high_voltage"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? What solved it for you? I'm having the exact same problem ("stack level too deep" after restarting the server, them "uninitialized constant Mail::Ruby19" on the same line subsequent times).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code from ContactController.rb is the culprit:

```
NotificationsMailer.deliver_new_message params[:message]
```

You do not actually have a method name deliver_new_message

Try removing it, and uncommenting the line below it:

```
NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The reason I left both versions in was that I had tried both :) I found the deliver_new_message version and tried it out thinking it might be rails magic syntax. Either way, they both error the same way.

Comment: Hmm, there are so many things that could be causing this issue. Is your code on github?

Comment: Stephen: It is, but it is not open source. Any ideas on things I could experiment with?

Comment: Just wondering if you are able to get this working in a standalone app, to test it in isolation. What does your form look like?