# contact form uninitialized constant contactcontroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contact-form, uninitialized-constant

Hello I am trying to implement a contact form following this guide: [Contact form in Rails 3](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/)

I am not using google apps but 1and1's smtp.

The error I get when I attempt to send the form is

```
Processing by ContactController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",       
"authenticity_token"=>"N48ORAhmDqTO7X2wsRlslMJ3l+v=", "message"=>{"name"=>"Patrick", "email"=>"patrick@yahoo.com", "subject"=>"Hello", "body"=>"Hello ME"}, "commit"=>"Send"}

NameError (uninitialized constant ContactController::NotificationsMailer):
app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

After some attempts at tweaking, I ended up just copying and pasting the code from the guide. Still have a problem.

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

def new
 @message = Message.new
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

if @message.valid?
  NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
  redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
else
  flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
  render :new
end
end

end
```

NotificationMailer

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

 default from: "noreply@misawahousing.com"
 default to: "info@misawahousing.com"

 def new_message(message)
   @message = message
   mail(subject: "[misawahousing.com] #{message.subject}")
   end

end
```

Comment: Have you restart your server?

Comment: Could you paste controller action code please?

Comment: @ Michael Szyndel Edited originai question

Comment: @michael-szyndel Help?

Comment: Do you have `app/mailers/notifications_mailer.rb` ? if you have, can you post it?

Comment: Updated the original post with the notification mailer

Comment: Did you update your routes as shown in the tutorial?

Comment: @Patrick : hope my answers help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `notification_mailer.rb` - `class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base`

change this (remove s)

```
 NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
```

To

```
 NotificationMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
```

Comment: Thanks didn't see the typo, but now I'm running into the error in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051056/rails-3-2-8-actionmailer-stack-level-too-deep-plus-uninitialized-constant-mail

Comment: If you found a new problem you could make a new question and accept answers or you post your solution on this questions